# Average of two incomes, taken from a normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

In a large corporation, people over age thirty have an annual income whose distribution can be approximated by a normal distribution with mean 60,000 and standard deviation 10,000. Two people are selected at random. What is the chance that the average of their two incomes is over 65,000?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be the incomes of the first selected person, and the second. Let $W=\frac{X+Y}{2}$.

Then $W$ has normal distribution, with mean $60000$ and standard deviation $\frac{10000}{\sqrt{2}}$.

You want to find $\Pr(W\gt 65000)$. This is probably a familiar sort of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
Lets $\ds{{\rm P}\pars{x} \equiv {1 \over \root{2\pi}\sigma}\,
          \exp\,\pars{\bracks{x - \overline{x}}^{2} \over 2\sigma^{2}}}$ where
$\ds{\overline{x} = 60000}$ and $\ds{\sigma \equiv 10000}.\quad$ $\ds{\pp\pars{t}: {\large ?}}.\quad$ $\ds{t \equiv 65000}$.

> \begin{align}
> \pp\pars{t}&=
> \left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd y\,
> {\rm P}\pars{x}{\rm P}\pars{y}\right\vert_{\pars{x + y}/2\ >\ t}
> =
> \left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd y\,
> {\rm P}\pars{x + \overline{x}}{\rm P}\pars{y + \overline{x}}
> \right\vert_{\pars{x + y}/2 + \overline{x}\ >\ t}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.%
> {1 \over 2\pi\sigma^{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \exp\,\pars{-\,{r^{2} \over 2\sigma^{2}}}r\,\dd r
> \right\vert_{\cos\pars{\theta} + \sin\pars{\theta}\ >\
> 2\pars{t - \overline{x}}/r}
> \end{align}

The angular integration is given by
$\pars{~\mbox{with}\ \tilde{t} \equiv {2\bracks{t - \overline{x}} \over r}~}$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} + \sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}
\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{\pi}\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} + \sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}
\,\dd\theta
+
\int_{-\pi}^{0}\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} + \sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}
\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sum_{\mu = \pm}
\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} + \mu\sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sum_{\mu = \pm}
\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} + \mu\sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}\,\dd\theta
+
\int_{-\pi/2}^{0}\sum_{\mu = \pm}
\Theta\pars{-\cos\pars{\theta} - \mu\sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sum_{\mu = \pm}\sum_{\mu' = \pm}
\Theta\pars{\mu'\cos\pars{\theta} + \mu\mu'\sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}\,\dd\theta
\end{align}
Since $\tilde{t} > 0$, the angular integration is reduced to:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} + \sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}
\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\Theta\pars{-\cos\pars{\theta} + \sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}
\,\dd\theta
+
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} - \sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}
\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&+
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} + \sin\pars{\theta} - \tilde{t}}
\,\dd\theta
\end{align}
Can you take it from here ?. Maybe, there should be some modification since incomes are positive numbers !!!.